# Scaling matrix transformed images for Compositing

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, scale, composite

I'm setting up a camera view where it has a image view over the top of it and uses matrix transforms to move the image around the screen. When I take the photo I want to be able to composite the image onto the photo with correct respect to location and scaling. The photo is only ever portrait and is rotated if it's landscape.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    this.newPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
    
    int photoWidth = newPhoto.getWidth() > newPhoto.getHeight()?newPhoto.getHeight():newPhoto.getWidth();
    int photoHeight = newPhoto.getWidth() > newPhoto.getHeight()?newPhoto.getWidth():newPhoto.getHeight();

    //Preview is fullscreen
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int previewWidth = display.getWidth();
    int previewHeight = display.getHeight();
    
    
    float scale = (float)photoHeight / (float)previewHeight;
    float scaleX = (float)photoWidth / (float)previewWidth;
    
    Bitmap finished = Bitmap.createBitmap(photoWidth, photoHeight, newPhoto.getConfig());
    
    //Create canvas and draw photo into it 
    //[snip]
    
    //Draw character onto canvas
    int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(character + "large", "drawable", getPackageName());
    if (imageResource != 0) {
        Bitmap character = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), imageResource);
        RectF rect = new RectF();
        float[] values = new float[9];
        
        matrix.getValues(values);
        rect.left = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] * scaleX;
        rect.top = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] * scale;
        //273x322 WidthxHeight of preview character image
        rect.right = rect.left + (273 * values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * scale;
        rect.bottom = rect.top + (322 * values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]) * scale;
        
        //Logging here
        
        
        canvas.drawBitmap(character, null, rect, null);
        character.recycle();
    }

    
    System.gc();
    newPhoto = finished;
    showDialog(DIALOG_PHOTO_RESULT);
}
```

Logs:

> Preview:480x854 Photo:1536x2048
>
> Scale:2.3981264
>
> Matrix:(112.45,375.85) scale:(1.00,1.00)
>
> Rect:(359.8342,901.34326) w:654.6885 h:772.1968

The image rect doesn't seem to be scaling large enough as the resulting composite image has the character too far towards top/left and too small.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that android was pre-scaling the character images which threw out all my scale calculations

By moving the character images into the `drawable-nodpi` folder I was able to stop android scaling the images for device so that the images can be scaled to match the camera views.

Comment: The other option is to use `getScaledWidth()` to take screen dpi into account